# Connecting jdbc from one docker container to SQL Server on another

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm going too preface this saying, I'm new to Docker.

I am using three docker containers:

1. SQL Server on standard ports
2. Coldfusion on standard ports

And I also have DBeaver on my host (correct term?).

Independently they both work correctly. I am able to see SQL Server from my host using dbeaver.

My issue is I cannot see SQL Server from the Coldfusion Docker container. The normal connection to databases from coldfusion is jdbc.

The error is:

> Connection verification failed for data source: nft-gis
> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket to host and port: localhost:1433. Reason: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Under normal circumstances, this feels like a firewall port issue, but again, I'm new to docker, and don't know how to get these two to see each other.

Is there a way to tell the ColdFusion container where the SQL Server container is, so I can connect?

Thanks

Comment: In ColdFusion, `localhost` refers to itself, not the other container. Are you using Docker Compose? If so, give the name for the sql-server container under `services` in the yaml

Comment: haven't learned yaml yet.  can this be added to a command line?

Comment: You don't need to learn YAML. Docker Compose is the recommended way to start multiple containers. Yes, the `docker run` CLI works too https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/

Comment: perfect.  I found the docker create netwoork components, added all the relevant coontainers, and used the 'internal" ip's to the bridge.  That worked brilliantly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> establishing socket to host and port: localhost:1433

It seems like you used the same connection string from DBeaver in ColdFusion? That won't work because `localhost` is the ColdFusion container.

At a high-level, you'll need to use commands like so

```sh
NETWORK_NAME="app-development" # for example
docker network create $NETWORK_NAME 
docker run --network  $NETWORK_NAME ... sqlserver 
docker run --network  $NETWORK_NAME --link sqlserver:sqlserver ... coldfusion
```

And then you should be able to connect to `sqlserver:1433` from ColdFusion.

Comment: You don't need `--link`.  So long as both containers are on the same `docker run --network`, their `docker run --name`s are usable as host names to talk to each other.